# Arguments Provided to an Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a custom sorting routine (`sortArray(a, b)`) to sort an array that I have.

If I call it like this

```
    a.sort(function (v1, v2) { return sortArray(v1, v2); });
```

everything works fine.

If I call it like this:

```
    a.sort(sortArray(v1, v2));
```

v1 and v2 raise errors, as being undefined.

Is there no way to utilize arguments passed by the .sort() method without creating an anonymous function to initially receive them, and then to pass them on to a user-defined function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort` expects a function reference, but you are trying to call `sortArray` and pass the return value of that call. You should just pass a reference to your function:

```
a.sort(sortArray);
```

Since `sortArray` already expects two arguments, it should just work, `v1` and `v2` will be passed automatically.

Comment: What a clear response!  That it wants a function reference absolutely turned on the light!

Incidentally, it returns a number, and sorting is done in acordance with the sign of the returned number.

Comment: Glad to help, @BrianWren! You're right that the comparison function should return a number, I forgot that.